# SMTP not sending email in production (IIS)

Tags: c#, iis, smtp

I have a function which on confirmed order sends an email to the client with order details, the function is an async Task which simply use `SmtpClient`.

The issue is that while i'm in debug in VS 2019, the mail is sent, but when i try to host the service to my local IIS no mails are sent..

My function looks like this:

```
   public static async Task<bool> SendRiepilogoAsync(string piva, int idOrdine)
        {
            var order = GetOrdine(piva, idOrdine);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
...

                using var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtps.aruba.it", 587)
                {
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx")
                };
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }

            ConfirmEmail(piva, idOrdine);
            return true;
        }
```

And it's called from a sync function (confirmOrder) like this:

```
 var emailTask = EmailHelper.SendRiepilogoAsync(piva, int.Parse(orderID));
```

Comment: That isn't calling it sync. Your code won't block on this line. Once it reaches the async part of `SendMailAsync`, it will return your Task object. The e-mail sending happens after this. You'll want to `await` that `emailTask` somewhere.

Comment: @John if i'd make the ConfirmOrder function `async` too by setting `await` to `emailTask` the API response from ConfirmOrder will take too long, and i want the email to be sent without locking the ConfirmOrder response.. which approach should i take at this point?

Comment: If this is ASP.NET Core, I'd be tempted to farm off any e-mail sending tasks to an `IHostedService` so that it can keep track of their success or failure.

Comment: SMTP will not work on a corporate Network.  Corporate Networks that have an Outlook Server will forward port 587 to a Proxy Server for a credential check and will not be routed to a third party email server like smtps.aruba.it